# Заменить for цикл по массиву на numpy без цикла

Tags: python, массивы, numpy, for

Как в этом коде убрать цикл и заменить его на numpy ?

```
def decrypt(data):
    sizepacket = len(data)
    if(data[len(data)-1] == 0xFF and data[len(data)-2] == 0xFF):
        data.pop(sizepacket-1)
        data.pop(sizepacket-2)
        sizepacket = len(data)
    for i in range(sizepacket-1):
        if(data[i] == 0xFF and data[i+1] == 0x0):
            data.pop(i+1)
    return xor(data)
```

Comment: Задача убрать _только_ один ноль если он следует сразу после 0xFF ?

Comment: Да, все верно нужно убрать только один ноль

Comment: У вас же в цикле стоит удаление элемента (.pop). Вы же понимаете, что в случае numpy использование удаление элементов из массива может существенно замедлить выполнение кода?

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

```py
import numpy as np
data = np.array(....)

# находим индексы элементов равных 0xFF и смещаемся на следующий элемент
indexes = np.where(data[:-1] == 0xFF)[0] + 1

# оставляем только индексы где значение равно 0
to_remove = indexes[data[indexes] == 0]

# удаляем все найденные элементы по их индексам
result = np.delete(data, to_remove)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вообще-то я очень сильно не уверен, что переход на numpy именно в данном случае даст какой-нибудь эффект. Я уже не говорю, про необходимость преобразования списка к numpy-массиву.  Но если очень хочется -  та вариантов может быть несколько:

**Раз:**

```
import numpy as np
data =[0x02,0xFF,0x01,0xFF,0x0,0x0,0xFF,0x02,0xFF,0x0,0x02]
np_data=np.array(data)
mask = np.ones(len(np_data), dtype=bool)
for i in range(len(np_data)-1):
    if np_data[i] == 0xFF and np_data[i+1] == 0x0:
        mask[i+1]=False
result = np_data[mask]
print (result)
```

**Два:**

```
mask1=[]
for i in range(len(np_data)-1):
    if np_data[i] == 0xFF and np_data[i+1] == 0x0:
        mask1.append(i+1)
result1 = np.delete(np_data,mask1)
```

Естественно, что в обоих случаях результат тождественный:

```
[  2 255   1 255   0 255   2 255   2]
```

Главное -  НЕ удалять элементы внутри цикла, а вынести эту операцию вне него.